# Simulating productive code in Java

Tags: java, database, jpa, simulate

Is there any way I could simulate my Java code, without really "doing" what is meant to be done in that part of coding?

So let's say I have an HTTP request, and that request basically is about updating a registration number of a person called "John Doe" but this would be only possible if that person is already in my DB for around a year.

So now I have my coding where I would have some method which checks, when that entry was made and according to that updates that row and send a HTTP 200 code as response or otherwise not do it because the entry is not already in my DB since a year and send a HTTP 400 as response.

**Now assume the following case:** some other consumer of my application maybe sends me 6-7 rows which he wants to update but he wants them only to be updated if all of them can be updated at once. So let's say out of those 7 persons, only 6 persons were entered a year ago into my DB and one was just added recently, then none of those should be updated in my DB and that consumer wants from myside a HTTP code 400 response.

==> So I need a new endpoint where I can do the checking if the entries can be update and kinda simulate the original coding.

Is there a way I could code that? I mean one option would be to use my method which does that check in the first implementation, but the disadvantage is still: in the end if the call to my DB goes wrong because of some JPA error or some coding which is behind that method goes wrong, this would not be handled correctly, since I would return a HTTP 200 if my method returns me that all entries can be updated but later on in the update process something goes wrong

Comment: Just write an endpoint to do what you're suggesting. Why not?

Comment: because as I said I have other coding behind that, which can still throw exceptions, that would be the disadvantage of that.... this is why I am looking for some kind of other idea maybe there is a way I could simulate the whole coding up to my DB actions

Comment: Your question is unclear. Just put an if statement or something. If the condition is not met, return a 400 and don't do the DB stuff.

Comment: Change your business logic so that you open one transaction for all seven changes. If there is a problem for one person you can rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: @vanje I might go with that or maybe just do the if clause in front of that method....